# how to find in android whether a location is between given two location?

Tags: android

**Suppose a person is going from Location A to Location D then suppose if i am going from Location B to Location D, then how to find out in Android using direction api whether my way comes between that person way.**

Comment: What is your definition of "between"? Any point on the globe is between any two other points on the globe.

Answer (score 1):

You have three points: A, B and C.
You know how to find the direction between two points.

So, if `direction(A to B)` is similar to `direction(B to C)` then B is roughly between A and C. Roughly. This will be less accurate near the poles and over longer distances.

Answer (score 0):

Using distance API (link below) you can calculate 
1.distance A to D
2.Then calculate distance from A to B and add distance B to D
If difference between 1 and 2 is zero,then its the same route

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro